# Referring to a selected item in a dropdown menu using DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there a way to reference a selected item from a dropdown menu implemented using select besides by index number?  For instance, I would like a javascript function that does something like:

```
if (document.getElementById("My_Select_Menu").selectedIndex.value == "Blue")
{
  do something;
}
```

but selectedIndex seems to return only a reference number to the first selected item.  It seems like there should be a way to reference the value of the selected item, am I missing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var sel = document.getElementById("My_Select_Menu");
if (sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value == "Blue") {
    // do something
}
```

`selectedIndex` returns the offset of the selected option (as an integer) so you need to use that to grab the actual element from options of the `<select>`.

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2cP7D/)

Comment: I did, wish that was always the case :)

Answer (score 0):

You can include JQuery and use this to do what you want:

```
if($('#My_Select_Menu').val()=='Blue')
{
 ...
 }
```

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

If all the options in the select have a value attribute or property set, then simply:

```
if (document.getElementById("My_Select_Menu").value == "Blue")
```

will do for all browsers since IE and Navigator 4.